# How to get url image when upload with GoogleDriveService

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, backend

I am using google drive as the photo storage of the application after uploading, but I have trouble trying to get the image path after uploading. How can I get the link? This is my code upload

```
$name = $request->file('thumbnail')->getClientOriginalName();
$image=  $request->file('thumbnail')->storeAs('/', $name, 'google');
```

If i use `Storage::disk('google')->allFiles()` . I get the following array

```
[
  0 => "130JDj2AYUyQd-9ABLHW86wXjtHdIOWdJ"
  1 => "1irMQMcYqnt8DSszOEqPKE5a7D30rib30"
]
```

I know it is random name, the photos I uploaded. but i need the url of each picture. What should I do ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FilesystemReader::listContents

```
Storage::disk('google')->listContents();
```

or

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$url = Storage::disk('google')->url('img.png');

dd($url);
```

or

You can use the below code.

```
$disk = Storage::disk('google');
$url = $disk->url('foo.jpg');
```